# Django - Return a file from Root folder via a URL

Tags: python, django, ssl, url, ssl-certificate

I purchased a SSL cert online and now ind the mid of verifying my host. How it works is:

1. It gives me a file
2. I have to make that file accessible through a specific URL on my host.
3. If the content of the file matches, it's verified.

Now I'm at step 2.

I'm trying to return a file (static) from an URL, as required by Comodo to verify my server. So basically, I think if I access this link:

```
http://your(sub)domain/.well-known/pki-validation/<filename.txt>
```

The guide is here:

https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/206957109-How-can-I-complete-the-domain-control-validation-DCV-for-my-SSL-certificate-

Can you guys help how I can return a file with this URL? Thanks!

Comment: You only need to verify the file once, so put that file in your root static dir, and change `STATIC_URL = '.well-known/pki-validation/'` in settings.py.

Comment: and that's all I need to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I actually found out that it was pretty straight forward.

I just put a path in my `urls.py` as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
      path('.well-known/pki-validation/xxxyyyzzz.txt', read_file),
            ]
```

Then my `read_file` function just simply return the file with

```
def read_file(request):
    f = open('.well-known/pki-validation/xxxyyyzzz.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    return HttpResponse(file_content, content_type="text/plain")
```

Comment: Tried all other methods and they didn't work. Just ended up doing this and it works fine and gets the job done.

Comment: didn't even need to open anything in my case just returned activation code in `file_content`

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Django app, place your file in the static folder `yourapp/static/.well-known/pki-validation/<filename.txt>`
2. Alias `/static/.well-known/` to `/.well-known/` in your app vhost

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>

   DocumentRoot /var/www/yourapp
   Alias /media/ /var/www/yourapp/media/
   Alias /static/ /var/www/yourapp/static/
   Alias /static/.well-known/ /var/www/yourapp/.well-known/

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Comment: Thanks! How do I perform the second step? How do I alias that in my app vhost?

Comment: `Alias /static/.well-known/ /var/www/yourapp/.well-known/`

Comment: I'm so sorry still couldn't figure that out. Where's and what's exactly app vhost?

Comment: Django application vhost == app vhost . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a work for Django to verify domain control, you should better verify your domain with CNAME record.
The guide how to enable ssl verification with django and nginx is here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/05/11/how-to-setup-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-django-application.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I ended up doing to make this work without needing to modify Django urls.py:

1. Placed <filename.txt> at /var/www/<your_django_site>/static/.well-known/pki-validation/<filename.txt>
2. Aliased /.well-known to /var/www/<your_django_site>/static/.well-known

Here's what the what the relevant parts Apache config VirtualHost entry should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    # ...

    DocumentRoot /var/www/<your_django_site>
    Alias /static /var/www/<your_django_site/static
    # This is the only line I needed to add to my existing Apache config to do HTTP SSL validation.
    # This will make it so that http://<your_domain>/.well-known/pki-validation/<filename.txt> 
    # will point to where you stored that text file and can be validated.
    Alias /.well-known /var/www/<your_django_site/static/.well-known

    # ...

</VirtualHost>
```