# How to access a txt file in django via url for verification purposes

Tags: django, ssl-certificate, settings

I have purchased an SSL certificate and I used an HTTP validation method where I need to store a text file under my server.

I am supposed to store is as `http://eblossom.lk/.well-known/pki-validation/ECB7.txt`. I am hosting through Linode(Ubuntu) using apache2. However, for some reason, my website cannot access the folder and gives me an error saying that the URL is invalid.

I know for a fact that if I type something like `http://eblossom.lk/static/style.css`, my static file appears, similarly, I need to allow my SSL certificate provider to get access to my `.txt` file the same way by.

Note: FOLDER NAME CANNOT BE CHANGED

I am sure something should be done with the settings.py file to allow access to open that folder, but I am not sure how.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: [Django - Return a file from Root folder via a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119949/django-return-a-file-from-root-folder-via-a-url)